# 'Never Block Sender's Domain' vs 'Never Block this Group or Mailing List'

Tags: microsoft-outlook

1. Kindly distinguish them?
2. How aren't they superfluous? Don't 'Group' and 'Mailing List' have domains too?  Doesn't never blocking sender's domain unquestionably entail never blocking a group or Mailing List?
3. Which option is broader or more sweeping? To wit, if I had to pick merely one option to avoid false positives (rather than unproductively clicking both), which to pick?

[Origin of screenshot beneath](https://www.howtogeek.com/398852/how-to-customise-junk-email-and-safe-senders-in-outlook/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we click “Never block Sender’s domain, Outlook will add sender’s domain to your Safe Senders List. Emails from Safe Senders List will always be received in your inbox. (Refer to screenshot below)

[image]

If you belong to mailing lists or distribution lists, we can click “Never Block this Group or Mailing List” to add these names to your Safe Recipients List.

The most common scenario is a distinguish group that you belong do. The group's messages are distinguished by the fact that the To address is always the group address. Therefore, putting the distinguish list's To address in Safe Recipients ensures that the group's messages will not be considered junk.

Comment: Thanks. i'm uncertain how this answers my questions 1-3? I still can't distinguish these 2.

Comment: “Never block Sender’s domain”: check email sender’s domain. If you click these one, emails from these domains will be treated as safe.

Comment: “Never Block this Group or Mailing List”: this will check message’s recipient which is a distribution list. If you click this one, emails sent to this distribution list (you are a member of this) will be treated as safe.

Comment: They are different options. I cannot say which one is broader and which one to choose depends on your situation.